# PyQt6 QWebEngineView adding white box

Tags: python, pyqt6, qwebengineview

When I add a QWebEngineView as an attribute of my QMainWindow, it adds this white box that shows the context menu when right-clicked. I do not want this white box in my program.

[image: link to image]

I do not actually use this QWebEngineView attribute for anything. My program creates tabs that show outputs from [plotly](https://plotly.com/) and each tab gets it own instance of QWebEngineView.

The simple solution would be to just remove QWebEngineView from my QMainWindow class and only add it to the tabs, but when I do that the window will close and open again the first time I add a tab. Not really sure what to make of that.

How can I remove this white box from my QMainWindow; or alternatively, how can I keep my program from closing and restarting the first time I open a tab and implement QWebEngineView?

I've tried searching for the name of this element so I could figure out how to disable it but I was unsuccessful.

**Edit:** Below is a minimal reproducible example. Comment out the QWebEngineView line in `__init__` to remove the white box and see the window restart mentioned above.

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebEngineWidgets
import sys


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # --------------
        # central widget
        # --------------
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        container   = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        # --------------
        # webengine view
        # --------------
        QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)

        # -----------------------
        # push button to add tabs
        # -----------------------
        btn = QPushButton('Add Tab')
        btn.released.connect(self.addTab)
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)

        # ----------
        # tab widget
        # ----------
        self.tabCount = 0
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def addTab(self):
        # -------------
        # main elements
        # -------------
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)

        # ---------
        # add label
        # ---------
        tabBrowser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        txt = '''
        <html>
        Hello World!
        </html>
        '''
        tabBrowser.setHtml(txt)
        layout.addWidget(tabBrowser)

        # -------
        # add tab
        # -------
        self.tabs.addTab(container, str(self.tabCount))
        self.tabCount += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # -----------------
    # exception handler
    # -----------------
    def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        main.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    # -----------
    # run program
    # -----------
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: @musicamonte I have added the example as requested

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you're describing (at least on Linux). Try removing the `self` argument of the QWebEngineView (it's useless anyway, since you're reparenting it).

Comment: Removing the `self` argument also causes the QMainWindow close and reopen behavior I mentioned. There is probably something going on with Windows since you cannot reproduce on Linux. For now I will just have the maximum size set to `(0,0)` since things look right.

Comment: It might be related to graphics aspects (QWebEngineView uses a private OpenGL based widget). I'd suggest you to file a report in the [qt bug tracker](bugreports.qt.io) (as a Qt bug, as it's unlikely that this is python related) adding detailed information about the Qt version (`from PyQt6 import QtCore; print(QtCore.QT_VERSION_STR)`), specific OS (version and build), details related to graphics environment (video card, driver) and any possible aspect that might affect the result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Assign the `QWebEngineView` as an attribute of `self`, then set the maximum size to `(0, 0)` like this:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebEngineWidgets
import sys


class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # --------------
        # central widget
        # --------------
        self.layout = QGridLayout()
        container   = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(container)

        # --------------
        # webengine view
        # --------------
        self.browser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        self.browser.setMaximumSize(0, 0)

        # -----------------------
        # push button to add tabs
        # -----------------------
        btn = QPushButton('Add Tab')
        btn.released.connect(self.addTab)
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)

        # ----------
        # tab widget
        # ----------
        self.tabCount = 0
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tabs)

    def addTab(self):
        # -------------
        # main elements
        # -------------
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        container = QWidget()
        container.setLayout(layout)

        # ---------
        # add label
        # ---------
        tabBrowser = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self)
        txt = '''
        <html>
        Hello World!
        </html>
        '''
        tabBrowser.setHtml(txt)
        layout.addWidget(tabBrowser)

        # -------
        # add tab
        # -------
        self.tabs.addTab(container, str(self.tabCount))
        self.tabCount += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # -----------------
    # exception handler
    # -----------------
    def exception_hook(exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        sys.__excepthook__(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        main.close()
        sys.exit(1)
    sys.excepthook = exception_hook

    # -----------
    # run program
    # -----------
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```